# Config of Drupal site using drush make and install profile

Tags: drush

I am getting started with using drush make and install profiles. I have been able to successfully have my site in a git repo and rebuild and install the site using drush. I have also been able to run some install settings, however, there are config elements that I cannot find how to set. For example, how would I install and enable a default panels layout for the default site template that is using panels everywhere and have that panel contain some content. I am aware I can export panels, but then how would I load them back in? What scope do I have for automating config in general on a Drupal 7 site? I heard it is vastly improved in D8.

Comment: You can use [features](http://drupal.org/project/features) module.

Comment: any alternative to features

Comment: No idea about module but you can do it manually, move schemas/tables  , which is not a good idea at all.

Comment: check out this post: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/71046/difference-between-using-features-strongarm-ctools-exportable-api