# Difference between using features, strongarm & ctools exportable api

Tags: features, chaos-tool-suite

Whats the difference between using features, strongarm or the ctools export api to export config settings? 
I cannot use the features modules so I need to find an alternative because its not part of the development process we use. What are the limitations with exporting config in general?

Comment: Try [Configuration](http://drupal.org/project/configuration), it's Features without the features - just config management. Might be worth adding in _why_ you feel you can't use the features module as that would help give some context

Comment: To make it even more confusing, lets add Drupal 8's config management stuff to the question.

Comment: That's covered by the Configuration module @Clive mentioned.  If you've not seen it, it's an attempt to backport similar functionality :-)

Comment: Just my two cents r: Configuration: I could NOT get on with it properly.  I much prefer having functionality of my sites built into "bitesize chunks".  I would be interested to know why you cannot use the Features module?

Comment: @Chapabu Taste's a funny thing ain't it - I absolutely despise features (always have), I was so happy when the decision to copy Symfony's configuration model was taken - we get proper config management in D8 and even in D7! It's a bit of a learning curve but Configuration is a lot less bloated than Features, produces more portable code, and is just nicer to use IMO. That's all in the strict context of Config Management though, obviously features has the whole "functionality bundling" concept as well. But personally I would always use a custom module + Configuration to do that anyway :P

Comment: anyone want to create an answer to the question?